# eclipse - how to create separate build configuration for multi-project workspace?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

My workspace contains 4 static lib projects and one executable project (which links these static libs).

Now I want to create separate build configuration where `TEST_GATE` is set, so in c++ code this `#ifdef TEST_GATE` evaluates to true.

So in all of my 5 projects I've copied `Release` configuration, named it `ReleaseTest` and added `TEST_GATE` symbol in project properties.

Now all 5 projects are build into new folder `ReleaseTest` and my problem is that i need to link static libs in the main project properties. I do this in C/C++ Build / Settings / GCC C++ Linker / Libraries, and this configuration is NOT configuration dependent. So I should select either "Release" version of static library or "ReleaseTest" version of static library. But I need to switch this automatically depending on what confuguration i'm currently building.

How can I solve/workaround this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Project / C/C++ General / Paths and Symbols / References you can change the configuration for every referenced project. After you change the checkboxes you can check the folder where eclipse is going to look for the libraries in the Library Paths tab.